# EF: using typeid map entity framework hierarchy

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, orm, hierarchy

i'm keep getting this error msg:

**Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'Extent1.RuleType' in 'field list'**

### my mapping:

```
public abstract class AlertRule
{
    private DateTime? _updateDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual AlertRuleTemplate Template { get; set; }

    public string RuleType
    {
        get
        {
            if (Template == null)
                return null;
            return Template.Name;
        }
    }
}
public class AlertOutageRule:AlertRule
{
    public virtual List<AlertRuleOutage> AlertRuleOutages { get; set; }
}
public class AlertMissingRule:AlertRule{}
public class AlertMetadataRule:AlertRule{}
```

---

```
        public DbSet<AlertRule> AlertRules { get; set; }
```

---

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AlertRule>()
            .Map<AlertOutageRule>(m => m.Requires("RuleType").HasValue("NewsOutage"))
            .Map<AlertMetadataRule>(m => m.Requires("RuleType").HasValue("NewsMetadata"))
            .Map<AlertMissingRule>(m => m.Requires("RuleType").HasValue("NewsMissing"));
            //.Property(m => m.TemplateId).HasColumnType("int");

        modelBuilder.Entity<AlertRule>().ToTable("AlertRule");
```

Comment: RuleType has no setter, so you cannot map it to a persistent database column, which is needed in order for EF to re-materialize the correct type when you retrieve objects.

Comment: @MortenMertner do you mean this property should have a correspondence column in database?

Comment: Yes; you must either add the setter (and thus the column), or remove all references to the property in your mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `public string RuleType` defined as read only (no `set{..}`).

EF will not map this property with database. see Your DB schema it will generated only 2 column (Id, TemplateId)

Comment: but i don't need a setter and don't want it map to database. any suggestions?

Comment: Then you can't use `.Map<AlertOutageRule>(m => m.Requires("RuleType")` because EF model will not recognize this property. try Data annotation or [MetaDataAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) instead.